# GoogleVisualr gem, undefined method to_js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-visualization

I am using a gem "google_visualr" to plot some histograms. I took an [example code](http://googlevisualr.herokuapp.com/examples/interactive/bar_chart) and tried to run it but I get the following message:undefined method `to_js' for nil:NilClass

my controller:

```
  def bar_chart

data_table = GoogleVisualr::DataTable.new
data_table.new_column('string', 'Year')
data_table.new_column('number', 'Sales')
data_table.new_column('number', 'Expenses')
data_table.add_rows(4)
data_table.set_cell(0, 0, '2004')
data_table.set_cell(0, 1, 1000)
data_table.set_cell(0, 2, 400)
data_table.set_cell(1, 0, '2005')
data_table.set_cell(1, 1, 1170)
data_table.set_cell(1, 2, 460)
data_table.set_cell(2, 0, '2006')
data_table.set_cell(2, 1, 660)
data_table.set_cell(2, 2, 1120)
data_table.set_cell(3, 0, '2007')
data_table.set_cell(3, 1, 1030)
data_table.set_cell(3, 2, 540) 

opts = { :width => 400, :height => 240, :title => 'Company Performance', vAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}} }

@chart = GoogleVisualr::Interactive::BarChart.new(data_table, opts) 

end
```

my index.html.erb:

```
<script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script> 
  <div id='chart'></div><%= render_chart @chart, 'chart' %>
```

Where is my mistake?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you hitting http://localhost:3000/[controller_name]/bar_chart?

I believe you are not and you are probably hitting the controller#show action instead,
and that is why the view cannot find @chart (nil class).